# ArcGIS JS API: How to get the lat/long of the viewport vertices?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I would like to get the min lat, min long,  max lat, max long of my viewport in ArcGIS JS API.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the Map.extent property? it will give the extent in the map units. If the map is not in wgs84, you'll have to project those values to lat-long.

Comment: Will this extent adjust dynamically once I start zooming?

Comment: Yes, the extent property gives the current extent of the map.

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/61326/124 Once one of these questions gets an accepted answer, the other should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the map's extent property, to get the extent. Usually your map will be in webmercator. we'll have to project the bounds back to EPSG:4326 in that case.

You can use the following code:

```
//asuming your map is in web mercator

//get the bounds of the current view
var bnds=map.extent;

//project the bounds from webmercator to latlong
var bnds_latlong=esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(bnds);
```

Comment: In my code I have the following requires: dojo.require("esri.map");
dojo.require("esri.geometry.extent");
dojo.require("esri.tasks.geometry");  Then I initialize the map and check map.extent.  I'm getting a dojo loader error, however: Error {src: "dojoLoader", info: Object}

Comment: map = new esri.Map("map", {logo:false});        
        map.addLayer(new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://geodata.npolar.no/ArcGIS/rest/services/inspire1/NP_TopoNordomr_U33_CHL/MapServer"));
        console.log(map.extent);
        console.log(map.extent.xmax);   // Am just getting 'undefined' for all this map.extent business

Comment: You map needs to be loaded, before you can query it for the extent. if you query it directly after adding the layer, without waiting for the map load, you will get errors.

Comment: nevermind got it working--had to use dojo.connect(map, "onExtentChange", showExtent);

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this, if your map is in web mercator, is to use [map.geographicExtent](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map.html#geographicextent).